# AppleScript to store diff of two files returns an error

Tags: applescript

I have two simple txt files, a.txt and b.txt.

a.txt

```
bla
```

b.txt

```
bla
bla
```

Next I want to store the output of diff in a variable like this:

```
set my_result to do shell script "diff a.txt b.txt"
```

This all seems very straightforward, but it returns the following error:

```
error "1c1,2
< bla
\\ No newline at end of file
---
> bla
> bla" number 1
```

How can I avoid this, and just store the result as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files don't match, `/usr/bin/diff` returns a value ≠ 0 and an error message in `stderr`.

AppleScript throws an error if a shell script returns a non-zero value, so you have to catch the error and get the error message

```
try
    set my_result to do shell script "diff a.txt b.txt"
    -- my_result is empty if the files match
on error e
    set my_result to e
end try
```